Simple request for help with geometric transformations and a problem I have.
The question
I have a problem where I have been given four options, but as far as I can tell, none of them are correct. Can someone help me understand the process of proving similarity?
So to my knowledge, similarity is proven by the process of transforming one polygon to another by using dilations, reflections, translations, and rotations. Congruence is proven by the process of transforming one polygon to another by using only reflections, translations, and rotations.
I have been given two polygons/triangles defined by the following sets of points.
$$
\Delta PQR = \{ (-2,3),(0,5),(0,3) \}\\
\text{and}\\
\Delta LMN = \{ (-3,2),(1,6),(1,2) \}
$$
I need to prove that these two triangles are similar, and they look to be, but I am unsure as exactly how to do so. The option available to me are

Dilate $PQR$ by a scale factor of 2 from point R and translate by the rule $(x+0,y+1)$.
Dilate $PQR$ by a scale factor of 2 from point Q and translate by the rule $(x+1,y+0)$.
Translate $PQR$ by the rule $(x+1,y+1)$ and dilate by a scale factor of 2 from point $P$.
Translate $PQR$ by the rule $(x+1,y-1)$ and dilate by a scale factor of 2 from point $R$.

My work
I worked through each of the options with my tutor and he says none of the given options are technically correct. He is helping me write this post as I write it to show me how to use this forum for specific and detailed questions. We think option 4 contains a typo and the dilation should occur with respect to R' (which is the result of the first listed translation). Unfortunately, as far as we can tell, none of the available options prove similarity since none of them take PQR to LMN.

The fourth is correct assuming that "scale factor of 2 from point R" is mentioned "scale factor of 2 from translated point R".

@user376343 is correct. The fourth answer is most probably the correct choice. The dilation should occur with respect to the center $R'$, the result from first translating the triangle PQR.
If you dilate with respect to this center, you can use the transformation formula
$$
T_c(X)=T(X-c)+c
$$
where the transformation $T(X)$ is just a dilation, and the input is $X-c$. A dilation simply multiplies $X-c$ by a scale factor of $n$. The specific result for just a dilation is
$$
\begin{align}
T_c(X)&=n(X-c)+c=nX-nc+c=nX+(1-n)c\\
&=(nx+(1-n)c_x,ny+(1-n)c_y)
\end{align}
$$
If you have any other questions please feel free to respond with a comment.
